# List months between two dates in snowflake table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a table with person's id, department, start date, end date as shown below:

**Source Table:**

[image]

I want to break the rows in months between the startdate and enddate for each id each department as shown below:

**Expected Output:**

[image]

I tried with Row generator in snowflake but as we need to get the different months between two dates based on each id's and dept name, I couldn't achieve it. Please suggest for possible solution.

Comment: did you try a generator, then row_number() and then datetrunc, and then dateadd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```sql
WITH Source_Table AS (

    SELECT ID, Dept_Name, TO_DATE(Start_Date, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS Start_Date, TO_DATE(End_Date, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS End_Date
    FROM (VALUES 
    (8797627, 'Dept1', '29/09/2021', '15/10/2021'),
    (8797627, 'Dept2', '29/09/2021', '27/12/2021'),
    (5489321, 'Dept1', '01/02/2022', '15/04/2022'),
    (5489321, 'Dept3', '01/01/2021', '01/02/2022')) T(ID, Dept_Name, Start_Date, End_Date)

), Gen_Month AS (

    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1)-1, TO_DATE('01/01/2000', 'dd/MM/yyyy')) AS Months
      FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 1200)) AS v
)
SELECT *
  FROM Source_Table AS st
  LEFT JOIN Gen_Month AS gm ON gm.Months BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC(MONTH, st.Start_Date) AND DATE_TRUNC(MONTH, End_Date)
 ORDER BY ID, Dept_Name, Months
```

Result:

| ID | DEPT_NAME | START_DATE | END_DATE | MONTHS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5489321 | Dept1 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-04-15 | 2022-02-01 |
| 5489321 | Dept1 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-04-15 | 2022-03-01 |
| 5489321 | Dept1 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-04-15 | 2022-04-01 |
| 5489321 | Dept3 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-02-01 | 2021-01-01 |
| 5489321 | Dept3 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-02-01 | 2021-02-01 |
| 5489321 | Dept3 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-02-01 | 2021-03-01 |
| 5489321 | Dept3 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-02-01 | 2021-04-01 |
| 5489321 | Dept3 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-02-01 | 2021-05-01 |
| 5489321 | Dept3 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-02-01 | 2021-06-01 |
| 5489321 | Dept3 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-02-01 | 2021-07-01 |
| 5489321 | Dept3 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-02-01 | 2021-08-01 |
| 5489321 | Dept3 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-02-01 | 2021-09-01 |
| 5489321 | Dept3 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-02-01 | 2021-10-01 |
| 5489321 | Dept3 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-02-01 | 2021-11-01 |
| 5489321 | Dept3 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-02-01 | 2021-12-01 |
| 5489321 | Dept3 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-01-01 |
| 5489321 | Dept3 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-01 |
| 8797627 | Dept1 | 2021-09-29 | 2021-10-15 | 2021-09-01 |
| 8797627 | Dept1 | 2021-09-29 | 2021-10-15 | 2021-10-01 |
| 8797627 | Dept2 | 2021-09-29 | 2021-12-27 | 2021-09-01 |
| 8797627 | Dept2 | 2021-09-29 | 2021-12-27 | 2021-10-01 |
| 8797627 | Dept2 | 2021-09-29 | 2021-12-27 | 2021-11-01 |
| 8797627 | Dept2 | 2021-09-29 | 2021-12-27 | 2021-12-01 |

Comment: don't use SEQ4() as they can have gaps.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim - It's a very small collection, but you're right, I changed it to ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: the problem with "example code on the internet that works with small data sets" but strangely not with large, is worth pointing out, every time. The doc's even warn of this exact point (the gaps, not the examples on the internet hahaha)

Comment: Thank you @SimeonPilgrim and MichaelGolos . This worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
with data(id, dept_name, start_date, end_date) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 'a', '2021-09-21'::date, '2021-10-15'::date)
), range_cte as (
    select row_number()over(order by null)-1 as rn
    from table(generator(ROWCOUNT => 100))
)
select d.id
    ,d.dept_name
    ,dateadd(month, r.rn, date_trunc(month, d.start_date)) as months
from data as d
join range_cte as r
where months < end_date
order by 1,2;
```

gives:

| ID | DEPT_NAME | MONTHS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2021-09-01 |
| 1 | a | 2021-10-01 |